# Yii2 How to access in controller to gridview columns and rows?

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

Good morning,

I have view with gridview and I need to access to value of columns of it in controller.

```
 <?=
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $misureIscrittiD,
    'columns' => [
          'id',
          'descrizione'
....
```

In controller can I get the value of each row of column 'id'?

```
$_POST = [
'_csrf' => 'Smpyb1VyZWtnLSdaZD0WAnk/FiQGOhZeegc/Ozk2Ng8wHjwWMBs/Hw=='
....
'id' => [
    0 => '5'
    1 => '6'
    2 => '7'
]
....
```

I'm sorry for my non perfect english.

Marco

Comment: show your controller code.and specify clearly what you want

Answer (score 0):

if you want to access models of your dataprovider you can use `$dataProvider->models`.
by this you can access to all models that exist in your dataprovider